# how to crawl asp webform link using scrapy

Tags: scrapy, webforms, web-crawler

I want to scrape a webform site but the links aren't regular hrefs they are like below:
and I want to have scrapy get that link and go there

<  a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DtGrdAttraf_ctl06_LnkBtnDisplayHadith" title="some title" class="Txt" onmouseover="changeStyle(this, 'lnk')" onmouseout="changeStyle(this, 'Txt TxtSmall')" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DtGrdAttraf$ctl06$LnkBtnDisplayHadith", "", false, "", "http://www.sonnaonline.com/DisplayResults.aspx?Menu=1&ParentID=13&Flag=dbID&Selid=8483", false, true))">the link text</ a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net is a form-driven framework. So, you have to fill in the form and manually post it to get to the page  directs?

How to do that?

At first, you can have a look at here, my scrapy code.
https://github.com/Timezone-design/python-scrapy-asp-net/blob/master/scrapy_spider/spiders/burzarada_spider.py

You should first find out what WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions() do in the page. You can just search the function by Ctrl+U, from the page source.

You will soon find out what it does, where does it fill these informations `"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DtGrdAttraf$ctl06$LnkBtnDisplayHadith", "", false, "", "http://www.sonnaonline.com/DisplayResults.aspx?Menu=1&ParentID=13&Flag=dbID&Selid=8483", false, true` in.

Then, the thing is clear.

You extract the href of the a tag to a string by

```
response.css('... a ::attr(href)').extract()[0].href # assuming there are many <a>s there
```

Then split the string `"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DtGrdAttraf$ctl06$LnkBtnDisplayHadith", "", false, "", "http://www.sonnaonline.com/DisplayResults.aspx?Menu=1&ParentID=13&Flag=dbID&Selid=8483", false, true` by commas, and, fill them in proper input elements and post it by `scrapy.FormRequest`.

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest( 

    'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx', 

    formdata = { 
        '__EVENTTARGET': eventTarget, 
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventArgument, 
        '__LASTFOCUS': lastFocus, 
        '__VIEWSTATE': viewState, 
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewStateGenerator,
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': viewStateEncrypted,
        'ctl00$MainContent$ddlPageSize': pageSize,
        'ctl00$MainContent$ddlSort': sort,
    },

    callback=self.parse_multiple_pages 
    )
```

Explanation:

```
https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx # url to post the form.
formdata # form data as json. keys are input names.
callback # function to get the response and do next things.
```

Viola! You can get into the page and the response can be got as an argument in function you gave as callback.

You can see some examples in the link above.